# Django Authentication: User Model Conflict

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I've a custom User model like this `class User(models.Model):` I also want to leverage Django's built in authentication system (which has a User model out of the box). I currently have a base template file for the application header where I would like to display the logged-in username like this `{{ user.username }}` This seems to be working fine except for the templates that are being passed the custom User model in the response context.

The model:

```
class User(models.Model):


  first_name = models.CharField(
      max_length=255,
  )
  last_name = models.CharField(
      max_length=255,
  )

  summary = models.CharField(
      max_length=4000,
      blank=True,
      default="",
  )
```

The template:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Here is the view method:

```
   app_user = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['user_id'])
   ...

   return render_to_response('common-dashboard.html',
                          {'app_user': app_user,
                           'entry': entry
                          })
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the problem? With your custom `User` model and that `render_to_response` you will have access to a `{{ app_user }}` variable in your templates

Comment: Can you post the `models.py`, `views.py` and your template?

Comment: edited, per @HenryFlorence request

Comment: @Jhakki is there an import conflict with `User` objects in `views.py`? Would `import django.contrib.auth.models.User as AuthUser` fix this? Or maybe the two objects being linked as in my answer below? The more code you post, the more helpful it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is now possible to create subclasses of `dango.contrib.auth.User`, but many sources recommend creating a `UserProfile` model which links to the `User` object with a one to one relationship:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):  
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  favourite_pizza = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  #other fields here

  def __str__(self):  
    return "%s's profile" % self.user  

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
  if created:  
    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)  

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

User.profile = property(lambda u: u.get_profile())
```

This should allow you to use `{{ app_user.username }}` and
 `{{ app_user.profile.favourite_pizza }}` in your templates. The code with an explanation is [here](http://blog.tivix.com/2012/01/06/extending-user-model-in-django/).